# problem with https://github.com/seehuhn/fortuna or maybe i misunderstand Golang

Tags: go

I am trying to use the https://github.com/seehuhn/fortuna for Golang and implement it into an API.

the problem i am having is when i assign *fortuna.Accumulator and assign it to my App struct i cannot use it outside of the function body it was created in.

see example below.

```
type App struct {
    Config config.Config
    RNG    *fortuna.Accumulator
    Sink   chan<- time.Time
}


func New(cfg config.Config) *App {
    var acc, err = fortuna.NewRNG(cfg.SeedFileName)
    if err != nil {
        panic("cannot initialise the RNG: " + err.Error())
    }
    defer acc.Close()

app := App{Config: cfg, RNG: acc, Sink: sink}
/// if i use app.RNG.Uint64() <---  using this here works correctly

    return &app
```

```
package main

import (

    "******/*******/app"

)

func main() {

    app := app.New(cfg)
    app.RNG.Uint64() <--- this causes Generator not seeded yet error

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you defering call

```
acc.Close()
```

witch effectivly killing RNG.